# Converting dates returned from Get-WmiObject in Powershell

Tags: powershell, shell-script

I am having issues formatting dates that I pull with Get-WmiObject.  I have found a few ways to work with them, but I have not been able to identify a simple way to format it as I need.  When I want to get a date with the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property InstallDate
```

InstallDate is returned as:

```
20170829172051.000000-420
```

I can get it formatted as a [datetime] object with this:

```
$InstallDate = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property InstallDate
$ConvertInstallDate = $InstallDate.ConvertToDateTime($InstallDate.InstallDate)
```

Where $ConvertInstallDate returns:

```
Tuesday, August 29, 2017 5:20:51 PM
```

However, I would like it formatted as MM/DD/YYYY  with no time, something like what you would get from running this:

```
Get-Date -Format d
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> $InstallDate = [datetime](Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate
> $InstallDate.ToString('MM\/dd\/yyyy')
05/22/2017
```